# Pycharm importing MySQL, generate_password_hash, check_password_hash error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm community edition 2016.2.1 on OS X El Capitan. I can install the packages `flask` and `werkzeug`, but I'm still getting an ImportError. How can I solve this?

This is the code that's producing the error:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

Comment: Where is the error coming from? The image is 3 lines of source code, and provides exactly no information about the source.

Comment: Can you show us the traceback msg?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, the error is under second line "MySQL" and third line "generate_password_hash, check_password_hash"

Comment: Hi Stephen, the command output is "40:496: execution error: The directory '/Users/duanyanjuan/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/qc/c2_8khrn0m35js_wn1tnf6ch0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging404/MySQL-python/ (1)"

Answer (score 2):

In your case it is helpful to create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), since it's not really recommended to touch the default Python installation that comes with macOS (virtual environments are almost always preferred to installing the package globally). Although it would be possible to install packages using sudo, as the error message suggests.

For users that are coming here because of the error that PyCharm IDE shows when importing the `werkzeug` hash functions, then try importing from `werkzeug.security`:

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

This will help your confused IDE make sense of the code.